# Dirty Regions on XBMC on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, xbmc, dirtyrectangle

I have a raspberry pi and have loaded the latest standalone from raspbmc.com. When using XBMC, I see that the CPU usage is always above 90%. After looking at the XBMC wiki and FAQs, dirty regions seem to be a popular way to reduce CPU usage.

I created a file `advancedsettings.xml` in `/home/pi/.xbmc/userdata/`. The contents of the file are:

```
<advancedsettings>
 <gui>
   <algorithmdirtyregions>1</algorithmdirtyregions>
 </gui>
</advancedsettings>
```

I tried modes 1 and 2 of [dirty regions as explained in the XBMC wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Dirty_regions), and in both the cases I see that only the region which is dirty is getting displayed whereas the rest is black. The [OpenElec wiki](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php?title=Building_and_Installing_OpenELEC_for_Raspberry_Pi#Enable_dirty_region_redraw_in_XBMC) says that this is a known issue in builds since August '12.

Now, what can I do to solve/work-around the same? I run HD movies at 1080p, and they work fine. But I am a bit worried about how long the RPi can take such amount of CPU usage, before something critical happens.

Comment: The processor in the RPi will take the load, ARM processors don't work in the same way as a x86 chipset will. They don't really heat up as much as you would think. It will take several years at 100% load before you notice anything bad happening. However, in saying that, there's no harm in wanting lower cpu usage, can only be beneficial to you, especially while multitasking.

Comment: The thing is I am running Raspbmc with streaming 1080p video over NFS, so the pi is going to be switched on for a very long time. So having the CPU usage near 100% is not something that I would want, and if there is *anything* that can be done to reduce the CPU usage level, I would go for it. But my question was mainly with regard to dirty regions, and it would be good if I could know how to get mode 1 or 2 working successfully.

Answer (score 5):

I have been playing around with various configurations in *advancedsettings.xml* and ended up using the following configuration [found at the Arch Linux ARM boards](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=3004&start=70):

```
<advancedsettings>
    <network>
        <cachemembuffersize>5282880</cachemembuffersize>
    </network>
   <fanartheight>560</fanartheight>
   <thumbsize>256</thumbsize>
   <gui>
       <algorithmdirtyregions>3</algorithmdirtyregions>
       <nofliptimeout>0</nofliptimeout>
   </gui>
   <lookandfeel>
       <enablerssfeeds>false</enablerssfeeds>
   </lookandfeel>
   <bginfoloadermaxthreads>2</bginfoloadermaxthreads>
</advancedsettings>
```

But still it had a CPU usage of about 80%. It finally dropped to around 20% when I enabled the *Vertical blank sync* in the *Video hardware* settings menu.

Also note that some skins can be very resource heavy. I had best results with the default Confluence skin.

Comment: I already came to pretty much the same advancedsettings.xml based on my search, but enabling 'vertical blank sync' is the magic trick and indeed reduces CPU usage to a steady 22% when idle.

Comment: I can confirm the same :)
would love to know why this magic is the case tho.